# How to send and receive the json object from one activity to another?

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I am facing the issues in sending and receiving the google json objects from activity to another activity.

```
 List<Integer> selectedScamMediumIds = scamMediumHorizontalAdapter.getSelectedScamMediumIds();
 JsonObject scamData = new JsonObject();
 JsonArray scamMediumJsonArray = new JsonArray();

 for (Integer scamMediumId:selectedScamMediumIds) {
     JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = new JsonPrimitive(scamMediumId);
     scamMediumJsonArray.add(jsonPrimitive);
 }
 scamData.add("scam_medium_id",scamMediumJsonArray);
 scamData.addProperty("scam_category_id", scamCategoryId);
 scamData.addProperty("scam_sub_category_id", scamSubCategoryId + "");
 scamData.addProperty("scammer_phone", phoneNumber.getText().toString());
 scamData.addProperty("scammer_location", scammerLocation.getText().toString());
 scamData.addProperty("lat", lattitude);
 scamData.addProperty("lng", longitude);

 Intent intent = new Intent(ScamLookUpActivity.this, ScamSearchActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("scamDatas", scamData.toString());
 intent.putExtra("scamSubCategoryText", subCategoryTitle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I have tried the above method, I don't know whether it is correct or not. Please help me how to send and receive the json object from one activity to another activity.

Comment: parse your `Json` into one custom Object, then make your class as `Parcelable` or `Serializable` to pass between activities

Comment: I don't know how to parse ...please will you post your code

Comment: We cannot help you generate/write a piece of code. We can just help you make a good logic. Your question shows that haven't done proper research!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass gson serialised object to Intent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761438/how-to-pass-gson-serialised-object-to-intent-in-android)

Comment: @ Zain how to receive and pass the received data to json object, in above link i am little confused in receiving side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the correct way. To get it in another activity, you can proceed as

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                String scamDatas = getIntent().getStringExtra("scamDatas");
                String scamSubCategoryText  = getIntent().getStringExtra("scamSubCategoryText");
                try {
                  JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
                  JsonObject scamDataJsonObject = parser.parse(scamDatas).getAsJsonObject(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: when scamDatas is applied to jsonObjectScamData , error occurring

Comment: OK, may be of casting.. You are using JsonObject and I used JSONObject.

Comment: JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonObject o = parser.parse(scamDatas).getAsJsonObject();

Comment: Please edit your answer i will accept your answer ..add JsonParser in your code

Answer (score 3):

Try

**1.** Send String via Intent

```
intent.put("scamData", scamData.getAsString(); //or scamData.toString();
```

**2.** Receive string from intent in other activity

```
String scamDataStr = getIntent().getStringExtra("scamData");
```

**3.** Parse json using `JsonParser`

```
new JsonParser().parse(scamDataStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put an entire JSONObject as a string. Something like this:

```
i.putString("scamData", jsonObj.toString);
```

And then in the MovieProductActivity you could

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("scamData"));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Send String via Intent

intent.put("scamData", scamData.getAsString();

- Receive string from intent in other activity

String scamDataStr = getIntent().getStringExtra("scamData");

- Parse json using JsonParser

new JsonParser().parse(scamDataStr);

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin enthusiasts,

Use data classes and use @Parcelize annotation, extend with Parcelable interface.

Can use intents in case of activity, one way to move between fragments - Use bundle.

```
Bundle().apply{
 putParcelable("some_unique_key",data)
}

val data = arguments.getParcelable<DataType>("some_unique_key")
```