# How to pass adapter to another activity screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to pass the Gson object to intent by using the below code and sen it to another activity for detail. I tried to use code from this instruction in comment, but still eror.. ( [How to pass gson serialised object to Intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761438/how-to-pass-gson-serialised-object-to-intent-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) )

This is my code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Beer> {


    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    public List<Beer> data = null;


   public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Beer> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = objects;

    }

    static class DataHolder
    {
        ImageView ivBeer;
        TextView tvBeerName;
        TextView tvDescription;
        TextView abv;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        DataHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);
            holder = new DataHolder();

            holder.ivBeer = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBeer);
            holder.tvBeerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBeerName);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            holder.abv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.abv);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else
        {
            holder = (DataHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Beer beer=data.get(position);

        holder.tvBeerName.setText(beer.name);
        Picasso.with(context).load(beer.imageUrl).into(holder.ivBeer);
        holder.tvDescription.setText(beer.description);
        holder.abv.setText(beer.abv);


// this is the trouble part: 

        Gson gson = new Gson();
            Intent intent = new Intent (CustomListAdapter.this, BeerDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("obj", gson.toJson(data));


        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the log so that the community can see the error and provide inputs.

Comment: Error:(103, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(CustomListAdapter,Class<BeerDetailActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CustomListAdapter cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CustomListAdapter cannot be converted to Context)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the `data` object to another activity, `BeerDetailActivity`, you have to "call" this activity to start by:

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

right after the line:

```
intent.putExtra("obj", gson.toJson(data));
```

However I am not sure if this is a correct thing to do inside the `getView` method of your `adapter`