# What's the best way to pass a whole recyclerview to another activity using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-recyclerview, custom-object

My RecyclerView in one activity is made up of an ArrayList of my custom object. Because this activity is in the edit mode, I would like to pass all the contents of this RecyclerView into another activity that is in non-edit mode. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two activities. You can achieve your goal with a single activity.
You can use some flag like `isEditMode` inside your adapter. It will be used to adapt interface for specific mode.
When you need to change mode -- just change `isEditMode` field and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Note. You also need change method `onBindViewHolder` of your adapter to react to a mode changing. Like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull K holder, int position) {
    if (isEditMode) {
        // Set up item for edit mode
    } else {
        // Set up item for non-edit mode
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't pass an entire `RecyclerView` object to another `Activity`. How about just passing your `ArrayList<CustomObject>`? You can do that with GSON:

[How to pass gson serialised object to Intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761438/how-to-pass-gson-serialised-object-to-intent-in-android)

Of course you can reuse the same `RecyclerView Adapter` class. You just need to instantiate it separately in both `Activities`.